# Android Canary dependencies for jetpack compose

Tags: android-studio, kotlin, dependencies, android-jetpack-compose, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I just started learning jetpack compose and I have a few questions

1. Should I use "Use kotlin script(.kts) for Gradle build files" and if yes what are the benefits?
2. Also how do I keep up with dependencies

   Dependencies from a [developers](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup) show older versions then the one in android studio canary.
   Some of them are either not there at all or version is different

do I need to include these

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.0.0-beta01'
implementation 'androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-rxjava2:1.0.0-beta01'

implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:1.0.0-alpha02'
```

do I need to include that

```
implementation 'androidx.compose.material:material:1.0.0-beta01'
```

or it was replaced by

```
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
```

where can I check new version and if it's compatible

```
implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha03'

implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha06
```

Included as default in AS canary

```
dependencies {

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:$compose_version"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling:$compose_version"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha06'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.+'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    androidTestImplementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4:$compose_version"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you can use both gradle and gradle.kts files, whichever suits you.

you can read about the benefits of kts in the [official documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html)

if you're totally comfortable with gradle files, there's no reason to switch, but if you're starting from the ground, I'd advise you to use kts

2. the current set of dependencies you always can find in [compose-samples](https://github.com/android/compose-samples)

This repo contains samples made by compose maintainers and gets updated on each release. You can subscribe to release notifications to always be up-to-date.

my current set of deps:

```
let composeVersion = "1.0.0-beta05"

"androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01"
"androidx.core:core-ktx:1.3.2"
"com.google.android.material:material:1.3.0"
"androidx.activity:activity-ktx:1.2.1"
"androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.3.0-alpha07"   
"androidx.compose.ui:ui:$composeVersion"
"androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:$composeVersion"
"androidx.compose.material:material:$composeVersion"
"androidx.compose.material:material-icons-core:$composeVersion"
```

Comment: Better androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0-beta01 instead of 1.2.0

Comment: What if ```kotlin-dsl``` is not an option?  ```gradle build``` does not compile if the ```kotlin-dsl``` is blocked(company infrastructure);

Comment: @JoãoCarlos I'm not sure what's exactly you question about, but in the official google samples https://github.com/android/compose-samples kotlin-dsl is not used, so you can check out those as a ref

Comment: I was getting the wrong configuration here, the console was complaining about some ```tsl``` version error; with the rc02, the ```kotlinCompiler``` configuration could be removed, so I did it and the error was gone after;